# Solve for $\alpha$: $P = \frac{1}{\sigma}\int_{0}^{\alpha} \exp (\frac{ -2 x^{\beta}}{\sigma} ) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to solve:

$$P = \frac{1}{\sigma}\int_{0}^{\alpha} \exp ( \frac{ -2 x^{\beta}}{\sigma} ) \;dx $$

This simplifies to:

$$P = \frac{1}{\sigma} \int_{0}^{\alpha} \exp (- B x^{\beta}) \;dx $$

But if we let:

$$t^{2} = Bx^{\beta}$$

And try to make it an erf, then:
$$2t dt = \beta B x^{\beta-1} dx$$

This could continue ad-infinitum. Any ideas? Or is a numerical solution the only thing we can do?

Update: So for $\beta = 2$, an analytical solution has been found. What about the case for $0 < \beta < 1$?

Comment: your "this simplifies to" step is not true at all. $\exp(a+b) = \exp(a)\exp(b)$ and $\exp(a b) = \exp(a)^b$ but $\exp(a b) \neq \exp(a)\exp(b)$

Comment: Yea you are right. Good catch!

Comment: However, you can use the change of variables $x = B^{-1/\beta} t$ (assuming $B > 0$) to make it
$$ P = \dfrac{1}{\sigma B^{-1/\beta}} \int_0^{\alpha B^{1/\beta}} \exp(-t^\beta)\; dt $$

Comment: And then with $t = s^{1/\beta}$, $$ \dfrac{1}{\beta \sigma B^{-1/\beta}} \int_0^{\alpha^\beta B} \exp(-s) s^{\beta^{-1}-1}\; ds$$

Comment: @RobertIsrael So then if $\beta = 2$ we can find the solution for $\alpha$

Comment: If $\beta = 2$ the solution is found in terms of the inverse of the error function.

Answer (score 2):

The antiderivative can be expressed in terms of the Whittaker M function or incomplete Gamma function.  But to solve for $\alpha$ will certainly require numerical methods.

Answer (score 0):

in general, even for simple $\beta$ (like $\beta=2$) there is no analytic anti-derivative. You could expand this into power series and integrate within the radius of convergence, but that would also likely place you in the realm of numerical methods.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think (as it was earlier mentioned) that it is not possible to express it in closed analytic form (only numeric solution), but for some cases, for example for $\beta=2$ one can do the following. 

 Set $t=(\frac{2}{\sigma})^{\frac{1}{\beta}}x$, then: 
$$P = \frac{1}{\sigma}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\alpha} \exp (- \frac{ 2 x^{\beta}}{\sigma} ) \;dx=\frac{\sigma^{\frac{1}{\beta}-1}}{2^{\frac{1}{\beta}}}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{(\frac{2}{\sigma})^{\frac{1}{\beta}}\alpha} \exp (- t^{\beta}) \;dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sigma}}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\sigma}}\alpha} \exp (- t^{2})\;dx$$
$$P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sigma}}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\sigma}}\alpha\right)$$
Then $$\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{\sigma}{2}}\text{erf}^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{2\sigma}P}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right).$$
Where [$\text{erf}^{-1}$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseErf.html) - is the inverse error function.

**UPDATE**

I think one can find analytic solution. Not pure analytic but rather “quasi-analytic” if it is possible to say so.

Changing the variable $t= Bx^{\beta}, \quad \mathrm{d}x=\mathrm{d}t\frac{B^{-\frac{1}{\beta}}}{\beta }t^{\frac{1}{\beta}-1}$ yields:
$$P = \frac{1}{\sigma} \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\alpha} \exp (- B x^{\beta}) \;dx=\frac{ B^{-\frac{1}{\beta}}}{\sigma \beta}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{B\alpha^{\beta}} e^{-t} t^{\frac{1}{\beta}-1}\mathrm{d}t $$

Using the definition of [the lower incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Definition):
$$ \gamma(s,x) = \int_0^x t^{s-1}\,e^{-t}\,{\rm d}t .\,\!$$
$$P=\frac{ B^{-\frac{1}{\beta}}}{\sigma \beta}\gamma\left(\frac{1}{\beta}, B\alpha^{\beta}\right) $$
Assuming that many CAS systems have algorithms for numeric inversion of gamma function (and its variations like incomplete gamma functions) ([for example you can use MatLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gammaincinv.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)) one can obtain the solution in the following manner:
$$\alpha=\left(  \frac{1}{B}\gamma^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\beta},\beta\sigma PB^{\frac{1}{\beta}} \right)  \right)^\frac{1}{\beta}$$
which is valid for arbitrary positive values of $P,\sigma,B,\beta$.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. So there are no solutions when $0 < \beta < 1$?

Answer (score 0):

As Robert Israel answered, the result is given in terms of the incomplete gamma function. This can can also simplify to $$P = \frac{1}{\sigma}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\alpha} \exp \Big(\frac{ -2 x^{\beta}}{\sigma}\Big ) dx=-\frac{\alpha }{\beta  \sigma }\,E_{\frac{\beta -1}{\beta }}\left(\frac{2 \alpha ^{\beta }}{\sigma }\right)$$ (provided $\Re(\beta )>0$) where appears the exponential integral function.

This is a very complex function of $\alpha$ and, as already answered, only numerical methods could solve the problem.